# NLog cpu performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have problem with this method in NLog library: `NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(object state)`

It consume too much cpu time. I have long running windows service using Nlog and after two days my service consume over 80% cpu time (one core is almost on 80%, second 30%). It is not 100% cpu time but it is changing and after cca 2 hours its back to normal. So I have run profiler and this metod maybe cause it: NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper.ProcessPendingEvents(object state)

I have 10 file targets all are setted as async. It is a fact that I have lot of logging in my app but only on level Trace, if I switched to Info level it not helped.

Can you help me, should I decrease logging in my app?

Comment: How frequently are you logging?  1000's of lines per second? 1 a minute? ProcessPendingEvents is simply called periodically on a timer inside the AsyncTargetWrapper class.  Could you elaborate on how much logging you are doing?

Comment: "I have run profiler and this metod _maybe_ cause it". Emphasis on _maybe_.

Comment: @MattC: It's hard to say. I have logging all over my app and frequency depend on logging level. I dont know how NLog works. Maybe it process all logs even if level is hight (imagine I have lot of trace log, but loging level is on Info so into file goes only Info logs ad highter). I dont know how to find this frequency. Any idea?

Comment: Svensson: That method was on the first place in CPU time profiling. Should by this method, I am 99 % sure that is that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://nlog-project.org/forum#nabble-td5896614) thread I would also guess that setting a higher number for [timeToSleepBetweenBatches](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/AsyncWrapper_target#AsyncWrapper_timeToSleepBetweenBatches) should reduce the high cpu time. Seems that the 2.0 beta of NLog should fix this behavor by only having one lazy writer thread running at a time.

In the meanwhile you don't have to change the source code to change [timeToSleepBetweenBatches](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/AsyncWrapper_target#AsyncWrapper_timeToSleepBetweenBatches). You can set it in the [configuration file](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/AsyncWrapper_target):

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
          name="String"
          queueLimit="Integer"
          timeToSleepBetweenBatches="Integer"
          batchSize="Integer"
          overflowAction="Enum">
    <target xsi:type="wrappedTargetType" ...target properties... />
  </target>
</targets>
```

> **Buffering Options**
>   *timeToSleepBetweenBatches* - Time in milliseconds to sleep between batches.Integer Default: 50

Comment: Ok, this is maybe that problem, but I am using NLog 2.0 beta. I will try code above.

Answer (score 3):

I took a brief look into the sources. My guess:

try to change ctor AsyncTargetWrapper(wrappedTarget, queueLimit, overflowAction)
...

```
this.TimeToSleepBetweenBatches = 50;
```

to something less frequent:

```
this.TimeToSleepBetweenBatches = 1000;
```

so the **internal timer** will not fire every **50ms** !

Comment: I could not change source code (dont want to) but maybe I can change it througt config xml. There is default asyncTargetWrapper settings: queueLimit - Limit on the number of requests in the lazy writer thread request queue.Integer Default: 10000
timeToSleepBetweenBatches - Time in milliseconds to sleep between batches.Integer Default: 50
batchSize - Number of log events that should be processed in a batch by the lazy writer thread.Integer Default: 100
overflowAction - Action to be taken when the lazy writer thread request queue count exceeds the set limit. Default: Discard

Comment: I have not try it yet. Will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `BufferingWrapper`, It only starts a timer when something is logged and not every 50 ms. Even if nothing is logged.

**Update** NLog ver. 4.6 now uses timeToSleepBetweenBatches=1, where it only triggers a timer event if something is written.